# Simple Registration (EE3) 1.6.2

Tags: simple-registration

The latest version in Devot: ee is 1.6.3 which is compilable with EE4.

If you buy this latest version, can you access version 1.6.2, which is compatible with EE3?

How can it be requested?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For EE add-ons, the market and culture generally always allows you access to previous versions. For top-level add-on teams, when you buy a current license for an add-on, you actually get EE2, EE3, and EE4 versions of the files in a single download.

But, the answer is to reach out to the add-on author if you can and find out.